# How to escape double quotes in HTML attribute value in Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby, escaping

Does ruby have some function to escape escaped quotes? like

```
name = "some \"thing\""
"<meta property=\"og:title\" content=\"#{name}\" />"
```

as

```
"<meta property=\"og:title\" content=\"some \\\"thing\\\"\" />"
```

Simple way is just do

```
name.gsub("\"", "\\\"")
```

but looks weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To properly encode a double quote in an HTML attribute value, there are several ways:

- You can use an unescaped `"` if the attribute value itself is delimited by `'...'` or vice-versa: (just like strings in Ruby)

  ```html
  <meta property="og:name" content='some "thing"' />
  ```
- If the attribute value is delimited by `"..."`, you can use the double quote's numeric character reference `&#34;`:

  ```html
  <meta property="og:name" content='some &#34;thing&#34;' />
  ```
- or its character entity reference `&quot;`:

  ```html
  <meta property="og:name" content="some &quot;thing&quot;" />
  ```

From within Ruby, you could call [`CGI.escapeHTML`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI/Util.html#method-i-escapeHTML): (I'm using Ruby's `%(...)` [percent string literal](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings) here for the meta tag string, so I don't have to escape all the `"`)

```rb
require 'cgi'

name = 'some "thing"'
meta = %(<meta property="og:name" content="#{CGI.escapeHTML(name)}" />)
#=> "<meta property=\"og:name\" content=\"some &quot;thing&quot;\" />"

puts meta
```

Or the [`tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag) helper if you're using Rails:

```
<%= tag(:meta, property: 'og:name', content: name) %>
```

Both of the above output:

```html
<meta property="og:name" content="some &quot;thing&quot;" />
```

Comment: thank you, not think about html encoded symbols way. but I prefer solution from another thread `'string'.dump`

Comment: @Dmitry note that `\"` isn't the proper way to escape double quotes in HTML attributes.

Comment: checked with google validator &quot; and \" are the same. But I checked place with json-ld, althrought posted in question example with html tag. Thank you for wide answer. Will use &quot;

Comment: @Dmitry try https://validator.w3.org/ – it will complain about `\"` and accept `&quot;`.